# Is there a way to change the color of the Apple information and the slider bar at the top and bottom of an iOS screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a forms application that has a dark mode.  However the Apple information that appears at the top of the display and also the slider bar at the bottom appear to very bright.  Is there a way to change the color of these?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top bar can only be black or white, or if you don't want to see it at all, you can hide it.

The bottom (tab) bar, can be influenced, you can use the Appearance APIs on iOS. For example, in your `AppDelegate.cs` file add a line like this: `UITabBar.Appearance.TintColor = Color.Red.ToUIColor();`

There are more advanced scenarios possible, have a look at my blog post about it here: https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/spicing-up-your-xamarin-formsios-tabbar/

And the (open) PR on the Xamarin.Forms repo here, which will makes this possible from the Forms framework directly: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/4899

Answer (score 0):

In app delegates.cs find Finishlaunching method and all following code. Also set the color accordingly.

UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(190, 18, 40);
UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes { TextColor = 
UIColor.Blue});